# Webpack 2 - Cannot create property 'mappings' on string

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

Migrating from a working Webpack v1 config to Webpack 2. But running into an error while trying to run the build:

```
 ERROR in ./src/index.jsx
 Module build failed: TypeError: /home/pierce/Projects/my-js-app/src/index.jsx: Cannot create property 'mappings' on string
```

I have updated my loaders to match the new format:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: "babel-loader"
    },
    {
      test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      query: {
        name: '[path][name].[hash].[ext]',
      },
    },
    { 
      test: /\.css$/, 
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        { 
          loader: 'style-loader' 
        },
        { 
          loader: 'css-loader'
        }, 
        { 
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: { sourceMap: true } 
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?/, 
      loader: 'url-loader',
      query: { 
        limit: 100000
      }
    },
    { 
      test: /\.icon-svg$/, 
      use: [{loader:'babel-loader'}, {loader: 'svg-react-loader'}] 
    },
    // Bootstrap 3
    { 
      test: /bootstrap-sass\/assets\/javascripts\//, 
      loader: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery' 
    }
  ]
},
```

It's as if something is not being compiled the way it was before, therefore causing a TypeError.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I was babelifing twice.

If you're also splitting your `webpack.config.js` into separate files for your different environments, be sure that `webpack.dev.config.js` does not include a `babel-loader` entry if your `webpack.base.config.js` does.

Otherwise, if you use the loader twice the 2nd time around will cause an error. This wasn't a Webpack 2 error but a webpack splitting-configs-and-missing-a-small-thing error

Comment: Simply perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered a similar issue in my compilation. Found out that I was using babel loader for `.js` and `.jsx` both.

Removed `.jsx` and its working as expected.

A snippet of my `webpack.config.js` looks like this.

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: [/(node_modules)/],
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'react-hot-loader'
        },
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
                plugins: [
                    'transform-class-properties',
                    'transform-decorators-legacy'
                ]
           }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is having the same issue, I had to remove the following from loader for it to work

```
     {
       test: /\.jsx?$/,
       use: ['react-hot-loader/webpack']
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped when I removed `devtool: 'inline-source-map'` from webpack